# Is jsdelivr cdn down?

Tags: jsdelivr

Is jsdelivr cdn down?

Bootstrap CDN gives for me ERR_CONNECTION_RESET so that affects many websites' design.

Please help me to solve this problem.

I'm from Egypt.

I expected to get the Bootstrap CSS or JS from the cdn but it gives me "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

Comment: https://status.jsdelivr.com/

Comment: It is giving me that is Operational

Comment: You will need to use a VPN service as I did. It is blocked in Egypt but I don't know why.

Comment: I'll add bootstrap css & js files on my website.
No other solutions, I think.
The problem that other websites that uses bootstrap it's design will be very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we noticed this too.
Try using `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` instead

Comment: FYI this isn't a valid answer. Also, if there is a transient service issue, such a question doesn't belong here.